# How to print array of arrays in this order?

Tags: php, arrays, printing

Hello guys please help I have array contains three arrays , each array contains a different amount of chars how ever the first array always have the greater amount of chars then the second and so on . Notice that two Consecutive arrays may have the same amount of chars check this example

```
array     //called lines
(
 ['a','b','c','d'],
 ['e','f','g'],
 ['h','i']
);
```

Am trying to iterate the main array and each time print the first letter of each array and then shift it out of the array so first time I will print 'a' from the first array shift it from the array and then move to second array and print 'e' and shift it from the array , move to the third and print 'h' the shift it then go back and do the same till all of them are empty so how can I do that here is what the output should look like "aehbficgd" sorry if the question is too long thanks

```
        while(!empty($lines))
        {
            $counter = 0;

            echo $lines[$counter][0];
            array_shift($lines[$counter]);
            $counter++;

            if($counter == count($lines))
            {
                $counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$lines = array
(
   ['a','b','c','d'],
   ['e','f','g'],
   ['h','i']
);

$continue = true;
while($continue)
{
    $continue = false;
    foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
        if(!empty($line)) {
            echo array_shift($line);

            $lines[$key] = $line;
            $continue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it here https://3v4l.org/TrcmA

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

```
while(array_filter($lines)) {
    $c = ($c != count($lines) - 1) ? $c + 1 : 0;
    echo array_shift($lines[$c]);
}
```

1. Filter `$lines` because it will contain elements with empty arrays, so won't be `empty()`
2. Check `count($lines) - 1`, because your highest key is 2 but `count()` is 3